# Pycharm does not see files in relative path with ../

Tags: python, path, pycharm, filepath, relative-path

I am developing a python project using pycharm. However, the problem is that it refuses to load files in which the relative path includes `../`. When I try

```
self.image = pygame.image.load("../resources/img/prey.png").convert_alpha()
```

I get:

```
self.image = pygame.image.load("../resources/img/prey.png").convert_alpha()
pygame.error: Couldn't open ../resources/img/prey.png
```

The thing is that when running my code from the terminal, it works fine, meaning that the problem is with pycharm.

Now, the problem is that while this originally sounds like many of the other questions in which the directory is not part of the working directory,adding:

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

from pycharm gives me `/media/Storage/System and dev/Code/Cross Platform/python/boids/current`

which seems correct with my directory structure being:

```
./current
    ./resources
        ./img
            prey.png
    ./objects
        modules_that_I_import.py
    ./experiments
        code_that_I_actually_run.py
```

The code that runs `self.image=pygame.image.load("../resources/img/prey.png").convert_alpha()` is in `./objects`

I am using `Pycharm Community Edition 2016.1.2` on Linux Mint with `Python 2.7`.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT

when running `os.getcwd` from the command line I get `/media/Storage/System and dev/Code/Cross Platform/python/boids/current/experiments`

Comment: What is printed when you run code with `os.getcwd()` in PyCharm?

Comment: the output I gave was when running it in pycharm

Comment: When I run `os.getcwd` from the commandline I get `/media/Storage/System and dev/Code/Cross Platform/python/boids/current/experiments`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to `Run - Edit Configurations`, select your configuration

[image: Run Configuration editing]

and change `Working directory` to `/media/Storage/System and dev/Code/Cross Platform/python/boids/current/experiments`.

[image: Working directory editing]

Comment: Your "change .. to" lists _two_ different directories : how can there be two for the single `Working Directory` ?

Comment: @javadba It is one path with names containing spaces

Comment: Are you saying that `/media/Storage/System and dev/Code/Cross Platform/python/boids/current/experiments` is **one** directory ? I am confused

Comment: @javadba Yes, I took it from the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I moved the python file to another directory. In my case, it was enough to delete the run configuration (`Run -> Edit Configurations -> Remove Configuration`).