# How to open files in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

as you can see from the title I am having difficulties opening files in pycharm. Every time I try to open a file it says: "Errno2: no such file or directory"

I already put the file in the directory my pycharm project is.

Here is a screenshot:
 https://gyazo.com/f9c12e266a4608ed8da3ccf9c6f9dbe3

Here's the code I use to open the file (I renamed the file to "filef"):

```
myfile = open("filef.txt", "r")
```

Comment: Describe exactly how are you trying to "open files in PyCharm". Your screenshot only shows an explorer window...

Comment: I write a piece of code to open it, like this: myfile = open("filef.txt")

Comment: Edit your question and add that code.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I put it in there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

First, check your current working directory:

```
import os
print os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
```

If it is not the path of your base project directory, then do:

```
os.chdir('/path/baseproject/directory/or/where/fileislocated')
```

Comment: Now I get no error and the code runs but the file doesn't seem to open anywhere. I dont know if this has to be like this or did I do something wrong.

Comment: @Danijel Also it's possible to specify working directory of running script in `Run Configuration` setting. For more details see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37655658/2235698

Comment: @Danijel what do you mean by "the file doesn't seem to open anywhere" - Be specific!

Comment: @wolframalpha I mean i don' see the text from the file or the file anywhere when i execute the code.

Comment: @Danijel if the file contains special characters, try opening the file in Unicode - by `import codecs; f = codecs.open("filef.txt", "r", "utf-8")` and then print !

Comment: @wolframalpha This doesn't work either, I still don't see the text from it anywhere, The text is just one word. By the way UTF - 8 was automatically put as default setting in my pycharm

Answer (score 0):

@Dani jel 
Solution below works for me. The easiest way how to do it is to use absolute file path and you have to use raw string as a file path with r in front of string or use double slashes or forward slashes.

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath(os.curdir)) # it´s different than file path, so I used the absolute file path in method open

myfile = open(r"C:\Users\Ghost\Downloads\special.txt", "r")
# or relative file path
# myfile = open(r".\Downloads\special.txt", "r")
print(myfile.read())
HELLO WORLD! # it´s from file
```